# reactjs How to pass a variable to a function inside setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a method inside ReactJS class called addTotal(price). Now I have to pass a variable to a function inside setState(), but it does not work:

```
    addTotal(price){
        this.setState(function(prevState, props, price) {
            return {total: this.state.total + price};
        });     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the function a value and save its returned value into state. The way you are trying to solve the issue seems illogical. Try this :

```
addTotal(price){
    let { total } = this.state;
    total = total + price;
    this.setState({total};    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The matter is that functions inside ReactJS setState() work only with this.state and this.props object. Therefore you need first to create a price property for this.state (this.state.price) and then to operate with it within setState like this:

```
    addTotal(price){
        this.setState({price: price, total: this.state.total});
        this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
            return {total: prevState.total + prevState.price};
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the section about [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and use the `prevState` instead of `this`. Besides that the function signature is not correct. It should look like this

```
 addTotal(price){
        this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
            return {total: prevState.total + price};
        });     
    }
```